# Find a Mobius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

Find a Mobius transformation by taking the ordered set of points $(0, 1 + i, −1 − i)$ to the ordered set of points $(1, −i, i).$

I've attempted this question many times and I end up with different answers each time. I'm using the cross ratio method but the answers I get are never correct

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Also it may be easier to go the other way.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The cross ratio method is the only way I know. And it's the way I use every other time. It's when I do the algebra that I seem to be making mistakes. I just want to see how someone else would do the algebra so I could see what mistakes I make

Comment: Put the question in the body of the post.  The body of the post should include the question you are asking, as well as additional context.

Comment: Please show us some of the many attempts you you made to answer the question.

Comment: @amWhy I've figured it out. I'm actually a complete idiot. I was doing it the wrong way round. So I was basically doing a map from z > w rather than w>z which I needed

Comment: You're not an idiot.  Glad you found your mistake, cuz that's the best kind of learning!  You should be proud for reviewing your work, to find where there may have been an error.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is similar to [Find the Mobius transformation which maps these ordered points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279156/find-the-mobius-transformation-which-maps-these-ordered-points/2279450#2279450)

Let the function be $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{az+b}{z+d}$.

Then $\displaystyle 1=f(0)=\frac{b}{d}$. So $b=d$.

Since $\displaystyle -i=f(1+i)=\frac{a(1+i)+b}{1+i+b}$, $-bi+1-i=a(1+i)+b$.

Since $\displaystyle i=f(-1-i)=\frac{a(-1-i)+b}{-1-i+b}$, $bi+1-i=-a(1+i)+b$.

Adding up, $2(1-i)=2b$ and hence $b=d=1-i$.

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
a(1+i)&=-b-bi+1-i\\
a(1+i)&=-b(1+i)-i(1+i)\\
a&=-b-i\\
&=-1
\end{align*}

So $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{-z+1-i}{z+1-i}$.

Comment: I know this is the correct solution. But the way I know how to do these is the cross ratio method. Now my exam is in 2 days time sso I don't really have time to change my approach. Thanks though

Comment: Seems you found a Duplicate, CY, and used it to answer the question here.  When you find such a duplicate, you need to close it as such, with a link to the duplicate post.

Comment: Oh, I see, your link takes you to your earlier answer to a problem posed by this asker. Hmmmm.